# Angular material flex layout - second container in the row doesn't move when resize

Tags: css, flexbox, angular-material

I am using an angular material layout. I have two containers in the row and I am expecting the second one to move under the first when I resize the page. The second container doesn't move under the first.

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Test</legend>
<div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
    <div flex="60" style="height:900pt">
        <divng-show="testShow">
            <div id="overlayDiv"></div>
            <iframe class="iFrameClass"  ng-show="showIfSelected"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div flex="40" style="height:900pt">
        <md-content>
            <md-table-container ng-show="showIfSelected">
                <table md-table>
                </table>
            </md-table-container>
        </md-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Without the CSS the above code is of little value. A [mcve] is required.

Comment: The code is using the angular material framework css

Comment: A Demo is still required. We don't have access to "angular material framework css"...not how you might have modified it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex 40% means it occupy 40% of the container. It doesn't matter the size of container. If you need a responsive design you can set minimum width to flex children. For Example you want one goes under another in width less than 400px:

```css
div.row{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    div.child{
       min-width: 201px; /* it is smaller than all mobiles. */
      height:100px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  
  <div class="child" style="flex:60;"></div>
  <div class="child" style="flex:40;"></div>
  <div>
```

In code snippet you can not change browser size.

Answer (score 0):

Your second container can't moves because with flex=40 and your first container flex=60, this sum = 100 and it's 100%.
With flex, your two container will stay always on the same row.